# Finding minimal generating sets of submodules of $\mathbb{Z}_d^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}_d^k$. A minimal generating set $G$ of $M$ is a subset $G \subseteq M$, such that $G$ generates $M$, and $|G| \leq |G'|$, for any other generating set $G'$ of $M$. I want to know the following:

1. Is there an efficient algorithm for computing a minimal generating set of $M$. Suppose that we are given $M$ in terms of a generating set, i.e. we are given a set $S = \{s_1,s_2,\dots,s_{\ell}\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_d^k$ such that $M$ is generated by $S$. If not, is it known what is the complexity class of the problem?

The naive way to do this will be to generate all possible subsets of $M$ and see if they generate $M$, and pick the one with the smallest size.

Comment: $M$ is given by the generating set $S$. So precisely $M = \{\sum_{i=1}^{\ell} a_i s_i : a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_d\}$.

Comment: I would calculate the invariant factors and use that. The algorithm for bringing a matrix to its Smith normal form is reasonably efficient. At least I think it would qualify. The number of invariant factors $>1$ gives you the minimal number of generators. The steps leading to the Smith normal form give you the matrices that change the bases to stacked ones, so you can also read the generators from there.

Comment: So I need to ask: are you familiar with the Smith normal form? If this stays unanswered (and there is no duplicate) I can try my hand later. Anyway, the Smith normal form is not too advanced, so very many users here can help you with it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Interesting. So if I put all the elements $s_1,\dots,s_{\ell}$ into a matrix $A \in \mathbb{Z}_d^{k \times \ell}$ as columns, then the Smith Normal Form says that $P A Q = D$, for invertible matrices $P \in \mathbb{Z}_d^{k \times k}$, $Q \in \mathbb{Z}_d^{\ell \times \ell}$, and $D$ a diagonal matrix of same shape as $A$. From this we get $AQ = P^{-1}D$, so $M$ is the same as the module generated by the columns of $AQ$ (or columns of $P^{-1}D$). So you are saying minimal number of generators equal nonzero elements of $D$. Can you briefly argue why this is the minimal number?

Comment: I was basically thinking about $M$ a finitely generated abelian group. It can be written as a sum of cyclic groups. A subset generates $M$ as a $\Bbb{Z}_d$-module if and only if it generates it as an abelian group. When the orders of the cyclic summands follow the invariant factor divisibility rules we know that we cannot reduce the number of summand, and hence we have a minimal generating set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can answer this question based on the comments of @JyrkiLahtonen above.

We start by putting the elements of $S$ into the columns of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{Z}_d^{k \times \ell}$. Then $M$ is the submodule generated by the columns of $A$, i.e. $M = \{Ax : x \in \mathbb{Z}_d^{\ell}\}$. The minimal number of generators of $M$ is given by the number of non-zero elements of the diagonal matrix of the Smith Normal Form (SNF) of $A$.

Recall the SNF: if $R$ is a principal ideal ring, then for any matrix $B \in R^{m \times n}$, there exist invertible matrices $P \in R^{m \times m}$ and $Q \in R^{n \times n}$, such that $AQ = PD$, where $D \in R^{m \times n}$ is a diagonal matrix. Moreover the diagonal elements of $D$ satisfy a "chain of divisibilities" condition, which I won't mention, as I don't need it in this argument, but can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form). The diagonal elements of $D$ are also determined uniquely up to multiplication by units (invertible elements) of $R$. The SNF is unique modulo these conditions on $D$. $\mathbb{Z}_d$ is a principal ideal ring, so the SNF applies for matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_d$.

One important property that easily follows from the properties of SNF mentioned above is the following: let $t$ be the number of non-zero columns of $A$. Then the number of non-zero entries of $D$ is at most $\min \{t,m,n\}$.

Also I think the following is true, though I can't seem to find an easy reference for this (may be someone knows a citable source): if the columns of two square matrices $X, Y \in \mathbb{Z}_d^{k \times k}$ generate the same submodule, then $X = Y P$ for some invertible matrix $P$. This fact has now been answered in this [MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437324/condition-for-equality-of-modules-generated-by-columns-of-matrices/437972#437972).

Now we return to the proof. We compute the SNF of $A$. So we get $AQ=PD$, and let us denote $PD = \begin{bmatrix} P_1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, where the number of columns of $P_1$ equal the number of non-zero entries of $D$ (and by invertibility of $P$ and uniqueness of SNF, the columns of $P_1$ are all non-zero). So we get that $M$ is generated by the columns of $P_1$. We need to show that this is also a minimal generating set of $M$.

Suppose there is a matrix $T \in \mathbb{Z}_d^{k \times q}$, where $q$ is less than the number of columns of $P_1$, and whose columns also generate $M$. Complete $P_1$ and $T$ to square matrices of shape $k \times k$ by adding zero columns, and call them $\overline{P_1}$ and $\overline{T}$. Then there exists an invertible matrix $U$ such that $\overline{P_1} = \overline{T}U$. If $\overline{P_1}$ has a SNF given by $\overline{P_1} = E \overline{D} F$ for invertible matrices $E,F$, then $\overline{T}$ has a SNF given by $\overline{T} = E \overline{D} (FU^{-1})$.

Now number of non-zero elements of $\overline{D}$ is less than $q$, and also equal to number of columns of $P_1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ is not principal ideal ring since it has zero divisors. $\overline 2\cdot\overline3 = 0$.

Comment: @Apass.Jack PIR is any ring where any ideal is principal. Not sure if you are confusing it with PID (principal integral domain). $\mathbb{Z}_d$ is a PIR but not a PID.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that smith normal form is valid for a [PIR](https://mathoverflow.net/a/362434/137630).

Comment: @Apass.Jack The Smith normal form and all the reuslting structure theory applies to finitely generated $\Bbb{Z}$-modules. I was simply thinking that $\Bbb{Z}_d$-modules are simply $\Bbb{Z}$-modules $M$ with the extra property that we know $dx=0$ for all $x\in M$.